# Recycler View not showing item in Samsung S8

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview

I am using `recyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`, within the scroll view. The items are being inflated in the adapter but are not displayed in the view. This specific issue is there in **Samsung S8** only. Rest all the devices are showing it properly.

```
    val layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity, 2)
    layoutManager.orientation = GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL

    val recyclerView = rvDropDownVideos
    val videoThumbnailAdapter = VideoThumbnailAdapter(activity, this, 
    videoList, videoUrlList, videoTitleList)

    recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
    recyclerView.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
    recyclerView.adapter = videoThumbnailAdapter
```

And the XML code is

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvDropDownVideos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_bottom"
            android:padding="@dimen/dp_10" />
```

Can anyone please tell me why there is view issue in S8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **NestedScrollView** instead of *ScrollView*.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using This

```
 VideoThumbnailAdapter videoThumbnial = new VideoThumbnailAdapter(activity, this, 
        videoList, videoUrlList, videoTitleList);
                recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(activity),2));
                recyclerView.setAdapter(videoThumbnial);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way it java code and remove all extra attribute if you are not using like isNestedScrollingEnabled and also remove in xml code android:layout_gravity because you give match_parent and match_parent.

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));

recyclerView.setAdapter(videoThumbnailAdapter)
       videoThumbnailAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```